# Order of elimination in Josephus p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, josephus

Josephus Problem (or Josephus permutation) is a theoretical problem related to a certain counting-out game.

> People are standing in a circle waiting to be executed. Counting
>   begins at the first point in the circle and proceeds around the circle
>   in a clockwise direction. After a specified number of people are
>   skipped, the next person is executed. The procedure is repeated with
>   the remaining people, starting with the next person, going in the same
>   direction and skipping the same number of people, until only one
>   person remains, and is freed. For example if n=10 then the order of
>   elimination is 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 3, 7, 1, 9 and 5

```
The problem is, without simulation of the above game, try to find out the order of 
elimination through means of mathematical formula or a mathematical pattern.
```

***Initially we are given n i.e the number of people in the circle at the start. Give the order of elimination keeping in mind the above conditions and constraints.***

In simple words, print the pattern of deaths without using any data structures like arrays and linked lists.

Comment: Why won't you ask this in http://math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Because I need to code the problem in C without using any data structures or arrays. Since stack exchange is a platform for programming related questions, I felt it belongs to here too. By the way I have already posted the question on math.stackexchange.com . @uselpa

Comment: Hint: you can use the call stack as your data structure.

Comment: Pretty sure you'd get a better answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Please don't double post: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1637699/147357

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have prepared the solution after studying http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~shamsbaa/Josephus.pdf .
This recursive is mentioned in the above pdf.

```
int last_man(int n,int x)
{
    if(n==1 && x==1)
        return 1;
    else if(n>1 && x==1)
        return 2;
    else if(last_man(n-1,x-1)==n-1)
        return 1;
    else
        return last_man(n-1,x-1)+2;
}
```

X denotes the xth person to die and n is the total number of people initially.
Looping this function over all values of x from 1 to n gives us the order of elemination.

Comment: can anybody guess the time complexity of the solution

Comment: You were asking for the order of elimination.  This gives only the last person standing.

Comment: substituting x from 1 to n  gives you the order of elimination, for x==n it gives you the last man standing

Answer (score 1):

```
function josIterative(n, k) {
let queue = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) queue.push(i);

let deathOrder = [];

while (queue.length !== 1) {
    for (let skip = 1; skip < k; skip++) queue.push(queue.shift());
    deathOrder.push(queue.shift());
}

console.log("Death order is " + deathOrder.join(" "));
return queue[0]; //survivor
}

console.log(josIterative(7, 3) + " is survivor");
```

This program is written in javascript es6.
Queue takes care to preserve the new position
Alternate way is to solve using recurrence relation

Answer (score 1):

There's an approach that uses ordered set

(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ordered-set-gnu-c-pbds/):

- Initialize an ***ordered set* V**, and insert the elements in the range [1, N] into V.
- Initialize a variable, say **pos** as ***0***, to store the index of the removed element.
- Iterate until the size of **V** is greater than 1, and perform the following steps:

  - Store the size of the set in a variable, say **X**
  - Update the value of **pos** to **(pos + K) % X**
  - Print the element pointed by **pos** in **V** and then erase it
  - Update **pos** to **pos%V.size()**
- Print the last element stored at the beginning of set V

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Header files, namespaces to use
// ordered set
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>
using namespace __gnu_pbds;

#define ordered_set                          \
    tree<int, null_type, less<int>, rb_tree_tag, \
        tree_order_statistics_node_update>

// Function to find the person who
// will get killed in the i'th step
void orderOfExecution(int N, int K)
{

    // Create an ordered set
    ordered_set V;

    // Push elements in the range
    // [1, N] in the set
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
        V.insert(i);

    // Stores the position to be removed
    int pos = 0;

    // Iterate until the size of the set
    // is greater than 1
    while (V.size() > 1) {

        // Update the position
        pos = (pos + K) % (int)V.size();

        // Print the removed element
        cout << *(V.find_by_order(pos)) << ' ';

        // Erase it from the ordered set
        V.erase(*(V.find_by_order(pos)));

        // Update position
        pos %= (int)V.size();
    }

    // Print the first element of the set
    cout << *(V.find_by_order(0));
}

int main()
{
    int N = 5, K = 2;

    // Function Call
    orderOfExecution(N, K);

    return 0;
}
```

**Time Complexity: *O(N * log(N))***

For better understanding, I recommend checking out this video:

https://youtu.be/KnsDFCcBJbY